# SUM Y COUNT en una consulta con left join en MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql

tengo un problema al generar una consulta en mi BD, voy a explicar de forma abreviada la estructura de las tablas de las que deseo realizar dicha consulta:

```
 **tbl usuario**
 - id_usuario 
 - nombre

**tbl alquiler**
 - id_alquiler
 - importe_total
 - id_usuario

**tbl impresion**
 - id_impresion
 - monto
 - id_alquiler
```

cada una de estas tablas tienen mas atributos, pero no las mencione por que no las necesito en mi consulta, y para no hacer mas larga la pregunta, básicamente  un usuario realiza uno o muchos alquileres, y cada alquiler tiene un costo total, ahora cada alquiler puede tener 0 o muchas impresiones(ya que lo que alquilo es un producto que puede imprimirse o no). mi problema es que necesito una consulta que me devuelva por cada usuario, la sumatoria del importe total de los alquileres que realizo, cuantos tiene y tambien la sumatoria del monto de las impresiones de cada alquiler si las tuviera o no. hasta el momento tengo la siguiente consulta.

```
SELECT u.nombre, SUM(a.importe_total) as TotalImporte,SUM(i.monto) as TotalImpresion, COUNT(a.id_alquiler) as Cantidad 
FROM Alquiler a
INNER JOIN Usuario u 
ON a.Id_usuario = u.Id_usuario 
LEFT JOIN Impresion i 
ON a.id_alquiler = i.id_alquiler
GROUP BY u.nombre
```

el problema que e tenido es que en alguno casos, un alquiler tiene hasta 3 impresiones, lo cual me ha afectado el count y el valor del importe total,nose si los estoy agrupando de forma correcta o que necesito cambiar en mi consulta ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Entiendo que el problema que tienes se podría resolver mediante una subconsulta sobre `impresiones`

```
SELECT  u.nombre, 
    SUM(a.importe_total)    as TotalImporte,
    IFNULL(SUM(i.monto),0)  as TotalImpresion, 
    COUNT(a.id_alquiler)    as Cantidad 
    FROM Alquiler a
    INNER JOIN Usuario u 
        ON a.Id_usuario = u.Id_usuario 
    LEFT JOIN ( SELECT id_alquiler,
            SUM(monto) AS MONTO
            FROM Impresiones
            GROUP BY id_alquiler
        ) I
        ON a.id_alquiler = i.id_alquiler
    GROUP BY u.nombre;
```

Ya que de los alquileres solo necesitas la suma de los montos, simplemente agrupamos por `id_alquiler`, lo que nos asegura que tendremos un único registro por `id_alquiler`, el `IFNULL` es para obtener 0 en caso de no contar con registros.

Comment: Era justamente la query que necesitaba, muchas gracias.